# Get parent FB event from recurring FB event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

Facebook recently added recurrences to their events. So a parent event 887104098135547, will have some `event_times` like so:

```
"event_times": [
    {
      "id": "887104171468873",
      "start_time": "2018-06-22T20:00:00+0200",
      "end_time": "2018-06-22T21:00:00+0200",
      "ticket_uri": "http://www.s-d-a.pl/zapisy/id29/"
    },
    {
      "id": "887104121468878",
      "start_time": "2018-06-15T20:00:00+0200",
      "end_time": "2018-06-15T21:00:00+0200",
      "ticket_uri": "http://www.s-d-a.pl/zapisy/id29/"
    },
    ...
```

If I start with event recurrence id `887104171468873`, I can fetch it and treat it just like a FB Event (name, start_time, end_time, description, place, etc). It represents the singular instance of that recurrence, its times, and the attendees.

However, there is no way to get the parent templated event id, as far as I can tell. And likewise, there is no way to tell that this recurrence event id is actually a recurrence and not a full id. :(

This is causing problems for my system, where sometimes it fetches Pages and gets the parent IDs (and uses them in the system), and sometim[[es it fetches Users and gets the events they're RSVPing too, and gets the recurrence sub-events, with no great way to figure out how to canonicalize them back to the parent ID.

Has anyone else figured out how to do this?

Comment: Doesn’t look like there is a direct way to make that connection. Not sure what exact problem this causes though, either. If you are fetching page events, then you can fetch the event_times to, and add them in your system, no?

Comment: The problem is I am trying to build an event database for my users. I am grabbing events from both Pages as well as individual user RSVPs. I was hoping to canonicalize on the parent IDs to save duplication in storage and display UI. Unfortunately I cannot, o may need to canonicalize on the leaves now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like this is confirmed as being not possible. FB knows it is an issue and it is on their roadmap. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/126142654873570/?ref=messenger_notif_bug_close